# Can not save session with VueJS (Front End) and NodeJs (Back End)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vuejs2

After generating session it will get back to front end (Vue Component) and then again it will go forward to back end (Node JS).Meanwhile,session suddenly lost.

I changed my code little bit in CORS({})
ya, 
Client = http://localhost:8080
Server = http://localhost:4040
Both are separated.

> > Api.JS

import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:4040",
        credentials: true
    })
}

> > App.vue

```
<script>
import LoginService from "@/services/LoginService";

export default {
    name: "app",
    components: {
        modal
    },
    data() {
         return {
         firstname: ""
       };
    },
methods: {
   async getAuth() {
       const response = await LoginService.getAuth();
       if (response.data.success) {
           this.firstname = response.data.profile.firstname;
       } else {
           this.firstname = "";
       }
    }
},
beforeUpdate() {
   this.getAuth();
}
};
</script>
```

> > LoginService

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
   getAuth() {
      return Api().get('auth/getAuth');
   }
}
```

Is there have any way to prevent session from terminate and it will catch in back end ?

Comment: you must have jwt token or Auth0 token to authenticate the user.

Comment: can you please specify with some information ?

Comment: How you manage authantication? you should store token in  localstorage on front end and on every request to back end you should send token. Read JWT web site https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken or so many